# Google Sheets Script "Exceeded maximum execution time"

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, maps

I'm having issues trying to deal with the "Exceeded maximum execution time" error I get when running my script in Google sheets. I've found a few solutions on here that I couldn't get working with my script. Any help would be greatly appreciated, here is the script I am trying to modify:

```
function getGeocodingRegion() {
    return PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('GEOCODING_REGION') || 'au';
}

function addressToPosition() {
    // Select a cell with an address and two blank spaces after it
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var cells = sheet.getActiveRange();

    var addressColumn = 1;
    var addressRow;

    var latColumn = addressColumn + 1;
    var lngColumn = addressColumn + 2;

    var API_KEY = "xxx";

    var options = {
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
        contentType: "application/json",
    };

    for (addressRow = 1; addressRow <= cells.getNumRows(); ++addressRow) {

        var address = cells.getCell(addressRow, addressColumn).getValue();
        var serviceUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address + "&key=" + API_KEY;
        // Logger.log(address);
        // Logger.log(serviceUrl);

        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(serviceUrl, options);
        if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            var location = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
            // Logger.log(response.getContentText());

            if (location["status"] == "OK") {
                //return coordinates;
                var lat = location["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"];
                var lng = location["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"];

                cells.getCell(addressRow, latColumn).setValue(lat);
                cells.getCell(addressRow, lngColumn).setValue(lng);
            }
        }
    }
};

function positionToAddress() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var cells = sheet.getActiveRange();

    // Must have selected 3 columns (Address, Lat, Lng).
    // Must have selected at least 1 row.

    if (cells.getNumColumns() != 3) {
        Logger.log("Must select at least 3 columns: Address, Lat, Lng columns.");
        return;
    }

    var addressColumn = 1;
    var addressRow;

    var latColumn = addressColumn + 1;
    var lngColumn = addressColumn + 2;

    //Maps.setAuthentication("acqa-test1", "AIzaSyBzNCaW2AQCCfpfJzkYZiQR8NHbHnRGDRg");

    var geocoder = Maps.newGeocoder().setRegion(getGeocodingRegion());
    var location;

    for (addressRow = 1; addressRow <= cells.getNumRows(); ++addressRow) {
        var lat = cells.getCell(addressRow, latColumn).getValue();
        var lng = cells.getCell(addressRow, lngColumn).getValue();

        // Geocode the lat, lng pair to an address.
        location = geocoder.reverseGeocode(lat, lng);

        // Only change cells if geocoder seems to have gotten a 
        // valid response.
        Logger.log(location.status);
        if (location.status == 'OK') {
            var address = location["results"][0]["formatted_address"];

            cells.getCell(addressRow, addressColumn).setValue(address);
        }
    }
};


function generateMenu() {
    var entries = [{
        name: "Geocode Selected Cells (Address to   Lat, Long)",
        functionName: "addressToPosition"
    }, {
        name: "Geocode Selected Cells (Address from Lat, Long)",
        functionName: "positionToAddress"
    }];

    return entries;
}

function updateMenu() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().updateMenu('Geocode', generateMenu())
};

/**
 * Adds a custom menu to the active spreadsheet, containing a single menu item
 * for invoking the readRows() function specified above.
 * The onOpen() function, when defined, is automatically invoked whenever the
 * spreadsheet is opened.
 *
 * For more information on using the Spreadsheet API, see
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_spreadsheet
 */
 
function onOpen() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu('Geocode', generateMenu());
};
```

Or, any other script you may know of that does geocode in Google sheets and already properly handles max execution time that would be OK too, I'm not tied to this specific script, just getting the outcome I need!

Answer (score 1):

This error's cause is due to script running more than 6 minutes.

A possible solution is to limit the time-consuming part of your script (which is the for loop) to only 5 minutes. Then create a trigger and continue the loop into another instance if it still isn't done.

#### Script:

```
function addressToPosition() {
  // Select a cell with an address and two blank spaces after it
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  ...
  var options = {
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
      contentType: "application/json",
  };

  // if lastRow is set, get value, else 0
  var continueRow = ScriptProperties.getProperty("lastRow") || 0;
  var startTime = Date.now();
  var resume = true;
  for (addressRow = ++continueRow; addressRow <= cells.getNumRows(); ++addressRow) {
    var address = cells.getCell(addressRow, addressColumn).getValue();
    ...
    // if 5 minutes is done
    if ((Date.now() - startTime) >= 300000) {
      // save what's the last row you processed then exit loop
      ScriptProperties.setProperty("lastRow", addressRow)
      break;
    }
    // if you reached last row, assign flag as false to prevent triggering the next run
    else if (addressRow == cells.getNumRows())
      resume = false;
  }  
  // if addressRow is less than getNumRows()
  if (resume) {
    // after execution of loop, prepare the trigger for the same function
    var next = ScriptApp.newTrigger("addressToPosition").timeBased();
    // run script after 1 second to continue where you left off (on another instance) 
    next.after(1000).create();
  }
}
```

Do the same thing with your other functions.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your response. This seems to almost work. It breaks properly before the timeout error is triggered, however, it doesn't seem to resume?

Comment: I also got a "Exception: This script has too many triggers. Triggers must be deleted from the script before more can be added." error when trying to run this script a second time. Thank you again for the help I very much appreciate it.

Comment: Can you provide a sheet @rob so i can test it on my side? The idea above should work but is currently untested. Also, i'll modify it once gotten a copy of your sheet.

Comment: This might take a while. But please do expect a reply within the hour.